# Radius of convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n+2}{2n^2+2} x^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to determine the convergence of the following series in dependency of $x$:

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n+2}{2n^2+2} x^n=\frac{3}{4}x+\frac{2}{5}x^2+\frac{1}{4}x^3+\frac{3}{17}x^4+ ... $

How can I solve this?

EDIT:
@Winther said, I should try the ratio test:

$q := \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| $

So we get

$q = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{\frac{n+3}{2(n+1)^2+2}}{\frac{n+2}{2n^2+2}}\right| =  \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{n+3}{2(n+1)^2+2}\frac{2n^2+2}{n+2} \right| = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{2n^3+2n+6n^2+6}{2(n+1)^2n+4(n+1)^2+2n+4}\right| = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{n^3+3n^2+n+3}{n^3+4n^2+6n+4}\right| $

With the tip from @Alex Vong to divide by $n^3$ the ratio test becomes:

$ q = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{1+3/n+1/n^2+3/n^3}{1+4/n+6/n^2+4/n^3}\right|= 1$

So now there is no clear statement if the series is convergent ($q<1$ convergent, $q>1 $ divergent).

Should I try another test (e. g. the root test)?

EDIT 2: Corrected the first coefficients.

Comment: Did you try the ratio test? It's the simplest test to apply and it works

Comment: The first numerical coefficients do not correspond to the general formula.

Comment: Can you find the [radius of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Theoretical_radius) using the ratio test?

Comment: Do you know how to evaluate that limit?

Comment: Notice you have a cubic over a cubic. So the limit is the ratio of the leading terms.

Comment: @AlexVong I'm not quite sure how to do it... I would just replace $n$ with $\infty$ and look if the demoniator or numerator is "stronger" (if it goes to 0 or infinity).

Comment: @Joe After you have expanded everything out, the standard trick is then to divide both the numerator and the denominator by some power of $n$. As Justin has mentioned, we have a cubic over a cubic. Therefore, the natural thing to do is to divide both the numerator and the denominator by $n^3$. Do you know how to proceed?

Comment: @AlexVong OK, I've divided by $n^3$. So the series is going against $1$? What to do now with $x^n$?

Comment: +1 for showing work after getting hints.

Comment: The downvoters should be ashamed of themselves.

Comment: @TheCount To be fair the downvotes was given *before* the question was edited, not after. Then the question had two lines basically just stating the problem.

Comment: @Joe The question asks for which $x$ does the power series converges. What you have shown is that the radius of convergence for this power series is $1$, which means that this power series converges on the open interval of radius $1$ centered at $0$ (i.e. when $x \in (-1, 1)$) and diverges away from it (i.e. when $x \in (-\infty, -1) \cup (1, +\infty)$. However, you still need to find out if this power series converges when $x = -1$ or $1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Powers of $n$
do not affect the radius of convergence,
only convergence at the endpoints
(since
$(n^k)^{1/n}
\to 1$).

Therefore
$f(x)
=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n+2}{2n^2+2} x^n
$
has the same radius of convergence as
$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n$
which is
$-1 < x < -1$.

At $x=1$,
the series is
$f(1)
=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n+2}{2n^2+2} 
$
which diverges like the
harmonic series.

At $x=-1$,
the series is
$f(-1)
=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n+2}{2n^2+2} (-1)^n
$
which converges 
because it is
an alternating series
with decreasing terms.

Comment: Your first line is always one I have trouble getting across to my calc students.  It's put very succinctly here!

Comment: @JavaMan Can you explain the first line to me? I understand, that the first part is convergent against 1 and if $\left | x \right | < 1$ the series converges. Why does the series diverge at $x=1$ and converge at $x = -1$ (Is this correct, or is there something switched?)

Comment: @Joe: I explained why the series converges at x=-1 and divergences at x=1. What didn't you understand?

Comment: @Joe The point is that if $f(n)$ an $g(n)$ are nonzero polynomials (or even nonzero powers of $n$), then $\lim_{n\to \infty}(f(n)/g(n))^{1/n}$, so that the ratio and root tests essentially ignore these functions when being implemented.  Therefore, when determine the interval of convergence, you can ignore them (except at the endpoints).

Answer (score 2):

If the ratio test works, there's no need to check with other tests; in your case you want to compute, for $x\ne0$,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}
\left|\,\frac{\dfrac{(n+1)+2}{2(n+1)^2+2}x^{n+1}}{\dfrac{n+2}{2n^2+2}x^n}\,\right|
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+3}{n+2}\frac{2(n+1)^2+2}{2n^2+2}|x|=|x|
$$
This limit is $<1$ if and only if $|x|<1$.

Thus the radius of convergence is $1$.

There are cases where the limit for the ratio test doesn't exist; other tests should be used. The “universal” test is Hadamard's:
$$
\frac{1}{R}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}
$$
but this can be difficult to compute.

Comment: It should be 1/R in Hadamard’s